# Android as Client for NodeJS Server, connecting to localhost and sending name-value pairs

Tags: android, node.js

First time using Android (native) as a client. I've been looking through a lot of tutorials and plenty of links. I'm still a little confused on a couple things that I wish to get clarification on. 
I understand that if I'm using an emulator I have to connect to `http://10.0.2.2`, correct? 
How exactly would I connect or display to my index page?  Normally it'd be `http://localhost:port`. But what about on android? Would I be using the URL class to connect and use `http://10.0.2.2:port/index` for instance?
I've seen a couple Get request tutorials but haven't managed to make any work. Let's take for instance a simple login. How can I send the name value pairs of "name"="test" password="testpw" to my back end so that it can verify these fields? From what I've seen a linked list with the name value pairs does the job, but I'm yet to actually make it work.
I might be thinking about this completely wrong (still going through learning process), and if I am what should I really be doing? 
Finally, I've seen a lot of links on tutorials here. Most of which help granted that there is already some knowledge on how to do this. Can anyone point me to some tutorials for beginners?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're writing the API in node and that it will be JSON based (would be stupid to go about it any other way). So you will need to create a background task for the http client (probably extend [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if you're going to send requests every once in a while). For working with JSON I would recommend [google gson library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Hopefully that will get you started. Without more information nothing comes to mind to help you.